# Access is denied when run the code

Tags: windows-services

When I run the code:

`SendKeys.SendWait("%({PRTSC})")`

This will not work. I get the error:

`Access is denied.`

If anybody has a solution then please answer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Services is a background application.  It has no interaction with explorer.exe  (only filesystem, registry)